# Duplication objects with .load()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for a better way or improved way of handling my Ajax call, currently my Gallery Objects (images) are being duplicated when making a request for them via .load()

I call the content of my Show action from my index page

```
<div id="project">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="project-media">
    <div class="project-slider">
       <ul class="slides">
        <% @gallery.gallery_images.each do |image| %>
          <li><%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:gallery_flexslider)) %>
              <p class="flex-caption"><%= image.image_status %></p>  
            </li>
        <% end %>
       </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="project-info">
  <h1><%= @gallery.title %></h1>
 </div>

<div class="project-category">
 <span class="border"></span>
 <span><%= @gallery.category.name %></span>
 <span class="border"></span>
</div>
<p class="center"><%= @gallery.overview %></p>

 </div>
</div><!--/#project -->
```

Index

```
 <!-- Portfolio Section -->    
  <section id="portfolio" class="section">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="title col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
     <h1>Our <strong>Portfolio</strong></h1>
     <hr>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Portfolio Filters -->
  <ul id="filters">
    <li class="filter" data-filter="all">All</li>
    <% @categories.each do |c| %>
      <li class="filter" data-filter="<%= c.name %>"><%= c.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <!-- End Portfolio Filters -->
</div>
<div class="portfolio-top"></div> 
<!-- Portfolio Grid -->
<ul id="portfolio-grid">
  <% @galleries.each do |g| %>
  <li class="mix <%= g.category.name %> mix_all">
    <% g.gallery_images.take(1).each do |i| %>
    <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:gallery_portfolio_home), class: 'open-project') %>
    <a href='/galleries/<%= g.id %>' class="open-project">
    <% end %>
      <div class="project-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i>
        <span class="project-name"><%= g.title %></span>
        <span><%= g.category.name %></span>         
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<!-- End Portfolio Grid -->
<!-- Ajax Loaded Portfolio -->
<div id="project-extended">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="project-controls">
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="close-project">
          <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="project-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Ajax Loaded Portfolio -->
<div class="portfolio-bottom"></div>
```

The show action gets appended to #project-content.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Portfolio filters
 $('#portfolio-grid').mixitup({
  effects: ['fade','scale'],
  easing: 'snap'
});

//Portfolio project slider
function initProjectSlider() {
$('.project-slider').flexslider({
  prevText: "",
  nextText: "",
  useCSS: false,
  animation: "slide"
});
};

//Portfolio Project Loading
 $('.open-project').click(function(){
  var projectUrl = $(this).attr("href");   

 $('#project-content').animate({opacity:0}, 400,function(){
   $("#project-content").load(projectUrl);
   $('#project-content').delay(400).animate({opacity:1}, 400);
 });  

 //Project Page Open
  $('#project-extended').slideUp(600, function(){
   $('#project-extended').addClass('open');
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-bottom").offset().top }, 900);
  }).delay(500).slideDown(600,function(){          
     $('#project-content').fadeIn('slow',function(){
      if ($('.project-slider').length > 0) {
        initProjectSlider();
       }
     });
  });

  return false;       

 });

 //Project Page Close
  $('#close-project').click(function(event) {
  $('#project-content').animate({opacity:0}, 400,function(){
  $('#project-extended').delay(400).slideUp(400).removeClass('open');
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-top").offset().top -60}, 900);
 });
 return false;
});

});
```

Apologies for the size of this but this is the output when rendering the show action, all my images are being duplicated

[image: dupliacted imges]

EDIT

refactored js, not throwing any errors but not loading the content within show action]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Portfolio filters
  $('#portfolio-grid').mixitup({
  effects: ['fade','scale'],
  easing: 'snap'
 });

//Portfolio project slider
function initProjectSlider() {
 $('.project-slider').flexslider({
  prevText: "",
  nextText: "",
  useCSS: false,
  animation: "slide"
 });
};

//Portfolio Project Loading
 var connect = function(link, success, fail) {
  $.ajax({
  url: link,
  success: function(data) { success(data) },
  error:   function(data) { error(data) }
 });
};

var animate = function(){
 $('#project-extended').slideUp(600, function(){
   $('#project-extended').addClass('open');
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-bottom").offset().top }, 900);
}).delay(500).slideDown(600,function(){          
   $('#project-content').fadeIn('slow',function(){
      if ($('.project-slider').length > 0) {
        initProjectSlider();
      }
    });
  });  
};

$(document).on("click", ".open-project",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).attr("href");

$("#project_content").fadeOut(400, function() { 
    connect(url, function(data){
        $("#project_content").html(data).fadeIn(400); 
    }, function(data){
        $("#project_content").fadeIn(400);
    });
  });

 animate();
});

//Project Page Close
   $('#close-project').click(function(event) {
   $('#project-content').animate({opacity:0}, 400,function(){
   $('#project-extended').delay(400).slideUp(400).removeClass('open');
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-top").offset().top -60}, 900);
 });
 return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refactor for you:

```
//Portfolio Project Loading
var connect = function(link, success, fail) {
   $.ajax({
      url: link,
      success: function(data) { success(data) },
      error:   function(data) { error(data) }
   });
};

var animate = function(){
    $('#project-extended').slideUp(600, function(){
       $('#project-extended').addClass('open');
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-bottom").offset().top }, 900);
    }).delay(500).slideDown(600,function(){          
       $('#project-content').fadeIn('slow',function(){
          if ($('.project-slider').length > 0) {
            initProjectSlider();
          }
       });
     });  
};

$(document).on("click", ".open-project",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#project_content").fadeOut(400, function() { 
        connect(url, function(data){
            $("#project_content").html(data).fadeIn(400); 
        }, function(data){
            $("#project_content").fadeIn(400);
        });
    });

    animate();
});
```

This should make the ajax call the data asynchronously, but act synchronously (uses callbacks). This means you'll be able to get the data properly (once). I think this will help you a lot, but may need some more fixes to prevent the duplication you're experiencing